# Store user preferences into an object and reuse them later

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to build an application that lets the user store his preferences into objects and later reuse them.

Up to now I have successfully stored the user input into objects in an array. Now I cannot figure it out how to use the stored input and reuse. The user names his color and chooses rgbo , hits save and his color is already appearing in the drop down list next to the button. He can have multiple choices. Later when the user decides to change back to some old appearance he needs to choose the color from the list and hit the Place button. Here is a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ANENaRid/1/)

I am looking for some guidelines on how to approach this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: There's no sign of JSON in your code. What have you tried so for?

Comment: I thought that  colors.push({
        name_prop:name,
        rgb_prop:rgb,
        opacity_prop:opacity
    }); is JSON or storing data in key value pairs.

Comment: It's just JavaScript. JSON is a data format.

Comment: So I am using the JSON data format right? If this is not JSON do you see a way to use the stored data and bring back the color from the drop down list?

Comment: No, you are using JavaScript. I'm still not sure what exactly you want. Can the user leave the page and come back or does he stay on the page and just select a value from the dropdown?

Comment: No it doesn't need to work between page reloads.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44338/discussion-between-henry-lynx-and-zeroflagl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have what you need so far, but the `Place()` function is empty. When the user makes changes to the sliders and clicks "Save", the `colors` array is updated properly with a new object containing the correct information. So `colors` *is* the object your asking for; You just need to do something with it in the `Place()` function. Here is some updated code that I will do what I think you're trying to accomplish:

```
function changeColors() {
    //get the numbers from the html
    var rd = parseInt(document.getElementById("red").value);
    var gr = parseInt(document.getElementById("green").value);
    var bl = parseInt(document.getElementById("blue").value);
    var op = parseFloat(document.getElementById("opacity").value);

    //convert the decimal into hexadecimal

    var rdhex = (rd < 16) ? "0" + rd.toString(16) : rd.toString(16);
    var grhex = (gr < 16) ? "0" + gr.toString(16) : gr.toString(16);
    var blhex = (bl < 16) ? "0" + bl.toString(16) : bl.toString(16);

    //concatenate all hex to generate a color
    var hexcode = "#" + rdhex + grhex + blhex;

    //set the background of the div
    setColor(hexcode, op);
}

function setColor(hexcode, opacity) {
    //view the change in the browser
    document.getElementById("div").style.backgroundColor = hexcode;
    document.getElementById("colordisplay").innerHTML = hexcode;
    //change opacity
    document.getElementById("div").style.opacity = opacity; 
}

var colors = [];

function Save() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var rgb = document.getElementById("colordisplay").innerHTML;
    var opacity = document.getElementById("div").style.opacity;
    colors.push({
        name_prop:name,
        rgb_prop:rgb,
        opacity_prop:opacity
    });

    //pass the object to the drop down list
    var select = document.getElementById("selectColor");
    var opt = name;
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.innerHTML = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
    console.log(colors);
}

function Place() {
    var select = document.getElementById("selectColor");
    colors.forEach(function(colorObject) {
        if (colorObject.name_prop == select.value) {
            setColor(colorObject.rgb_prop, colorObject.opacity_prop);
        }
    });               
}
```

Note that all of this is only going to exist during the user's visit to this page. Once they reload the page, the data is is gone. If you want to save things for later visits to the page, you're looking at a more complicated solution.

Comment: Yes, I do understand this. What I do not seem to get is how to get the name, rgb and opacity from the object in the colors array and change the color of the div.

Comment: I edited my answer to show an example of looping through the colors array.

Comment: Actually, I see more what you're asking now. I will update my answer to show you how to actually change the color of the div.